# Why does declaring and using a global function compile but does not run?

Tags: typescript

I have two typescript files.

**`file1.ts`**, with only 3 lines where I declare a function in the *global scope* (see [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)):

```js
function hello() : void {
    console.log("hello")
}
```

**`file2.ts`**, with only 1 line where I use the function available in the global scope:

```js
hello()
```

I can compile them just fine:

```
$ tsc file1.ts file2.ts
```

But then if I run `file2.ts`, the global function cannot be found:

```
$ node file2.js
/tmp/file2.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { hello();
                                                              ^

ReferenceError: hello is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/file2.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

Yet the typescript documentation says that everything outside a module is global and can be used anywhere, and indeed it does compile. Even Visual Studio Code is OK with that and allows me to CTRL+click on `hello` in `file2.ts` and it brings me to `file1.ts`.

But why doesn't it run?

---

**EDIT:** A coment suggested that this is a limitation of node.js. Thence I tried running all this in a browser using this html file:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js"></script>
```

And indeed this time it works! The culprit seems to be node.js, as it cannot take multiple files as input, and cannot therefore fulfill this part of the typescript specification at runtime.

---

**EDIT 2:** Another workaround I found is to ask the compiler to produce one single `.js` file as output using `--outFile`, which is much friendlier for node.js and trivially solves this global scope situation.

```
$ tsc --outFile out.js file1.ts file2.ts
$ node out.js
hello
```

---

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: @JGFMK This is the link I have put in my question. And it says "Conversely, a file without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well)". I am trying to understand this notion of global scope, which seems to work at compile time but not at runtime.

Comment: Typescript treats it as a global script, node does not, node only executes modules. You can run this in the browser maybe `file2.js` is included with a script tag while `file1.js` is imported with a module system.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks! I've added a comment to my question based on that.

Comment: Did you also see the mention of commonjs or require.js. Perhaps have a look at the way things like Angular do it too, to get an idea of how things work in the bigger frameworks. Maybe here first though. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html